# Are the density of states of bonding and the corresponding antibonding states complementary?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, solid-state-chemistry

As for the bonding and the corresponding antibonding molecular orbitals formed between two types of atomic orbitals, are their density of states (DOS) complementary? This means if the DOS of the bonding states is high, then the DOS of the antibonding states is low, and vice versa.

Intuitively, I think it is a correct statement since the total DOS of the two types of atomic orbitals is a constant, but I can't find a reference which discusses this point.

Comment: Since mathematically speaking antibonding orbitals are more antibonding then bonding orbitals are bonding, I want to say no.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I don't fully understand, can you elaborate your point a little bit?

Comment: Actually I can't, I don't remember what I wanted to say and I don't understand what I meant. I'm just usually cautious, because there seldom is something ready or some about orbitals.